# how to run PHP scripts live in Vim

Tags: php, vim

I am a newbie and want to a run a PHP script in Vim .. without checking the outputs in a browser i want to see its output in vim , to speed up my learning process

For example :

if i write this in Vim editor

```
<?php
      $name="Leo";
      $age = "15";

      printf("My name is %s and I am %d",$name,$age); 
?>
```

rather than saving it and running it through Wamp/Xampp i want to see its output in Vim, Just like we can see the expected output of HTML in browser via Inspect Element Technique

Thanks

Comment: It depends if you are wanting to see output from a file that uses CGI (your small example does not), where you would actually have to  execute it with an HTTP request on your web server via something like `lynx` or `wget` to see the output.  If it is only for simple scripts like the one above, you can just `:!php %`

Comment: I'm not familiar with wamp/xampp.  Does a command like this return the expected html from the php?  `wamp file.php`

Comment: Can't you just use php-cli?